# Modulo of long long int number

Tags: c, modulo, unsigned-long-long-int

Hi i tried out a code in c and considering that all variables in the following line of code were of "long long int",

> money=(money % 1000000007)+(((2*pow(abs(a[i]-a[j]),k))%1000000007) %        1000000007);

i received an error which states that

`error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'double' and 'int')
money=(money % 1000000007)+(((2*pow(abs(a[i]-a[j]),k))%1000000007))) % 1000000007);
                                                      ^`

I did not understand what the error meant in this case because i did not use double.Could i get a brief explanation ?

Comment: `pow()` returns a `double`. Cast it.

Comment: You can avoid floating point arithmetic altogether by writing your own efficient `power` function which works off powers of 2 (applying your modulus at each step). For example `x**20 = x**16 * x**4`. It is efficient for large powers, requiring only (num bits in power variable) loops.

Comment: `abs(a[i]-a[j])` returns `int`, not `long long`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

% is an integer operator and pow() returns a double. So, you may need to use  fmod or fmodf or convert everything to int.

```
money=(money % 1000000007)+(((2*(long long int)pow(abs(a[i]-a[j]),k))%1000000007))) % 1000000007);
```

Comment: _money=(money % 1000000007)+(((2*( **long long int** )Math.pow(abs(a[i]-a[j]),k))%1000000007))) % 1000000007);_

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera You can edit the answer. I dont mind.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with pow. If you look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/ you will see that regardless of what type you give it, it will return either a float or a double.

Try casting the result of pow to an int

Comment: `pow()` always returns a double.  `powf()` is the float version.

Comment: @NovaDenizen you are correct for some versions of c++. Not an expert, but it looks like c++11 renamed it back to pow.

Comment: This question is tagged as "C".